# Coordinate Changes of Centers Of Two Spheres

Tags: calculus

I tutored a high school student last week and one of his questions is:

**Question:** Find a transformation which takes the two spheres $P_1, P_2$ of centers $(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ of radii $a,b$ respectively to the two spheres of the same radii but centers at the origin and the other at $Q = (d,0,0)$ with $d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2+(y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2} > 0$.

What I came up with is that I let $u = x - x_1, v = y - y_1, w = z - z_1$ and this transformation takes the first sphere's center to the origin. Then I go on and set $u' = u + d - x_2, v' = v - y_2,w' = w - z_2$. Would the last set of equations be the right transformation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the proper transformation includes a *homothety*--one of the Affine transformations that translates each point toward (or away from) the "homothetic center" by an amount proportional to its distance from that center.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution (so please don't downvote), but an outline of a solution (too long to place in a comment).

You want to cascade several Affine transformations, expressed as $4 \times 4$ matrices) where each point in the space is represented by an "augmented" vector, such as $(x,y,z,1)^t$.  The matrices should be as follows:

${\bf M}_1$ is a simple translation to place sphere $1$ at the origin.  Sphere $2$ will lie at a new shifted position.

Find the vector that lies halfway the $x$ axis and the vector linking the centers of sphere 1 and the center of the translated sphere $2$.  Call this vector ${\bf v}$.

${\bf M}_2$ is a rotation of the space about ${\bf v}$ by an angle $\pi$.  This will leave sphere $1$ at the origin but take sphere $2$ to the $x$ axis.

Now you have the two spheres on the $x$ axis (as desired).  Sphere $1$ is at the origin but sphere $2$ is at some position $(D,0,0)$ with its original radius.

Now perform a homothety.  Find the point ${\bf C}$ on the $x$ axis (that will be the "homothetic center") such that the distances to the centers of the spheres are in the ratio of the spheres' radii.

${\bf M}_3$ is a homothety, "squeezing" the sphere most distant from ${\bf C}$ more than the nearby sphere.  Set the scaling parameter (typically called $\lambda$) such that the spheres have equal radii.

${\bf M}_4$ is a simple translation to return sphere $1$ to the origin (and sphere $2$ to a new position on the $x$ axis).  Note that they have the same radii.

${\bf M}_5$ is an overall scale to adjust the radii to the desired final radii.

Multiply all these Affine matrices to get the single overall transformation.